# MVC, PDF response auto print

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I am working with C# and MVC4, I am trying to open the print dialog when the pdf document is opened by clicking on print button by user.

I Google it, but I could not find any better solution for this.

One thing i can do is, I can create one view and embed the pdf document to the view then on open i can have jquery method to print the document. Is it a correct way?

Please suggest.

Comment: I have tried different ways and able to open the print dialog, but main problem with Mozilla it does not listen the print command or it prints the empty page...

Answer (score 0):

Calling print in the HTML document does not have to call the print in the PDF document displayed by the PDF plugin. Some browsers do seem to call the print command of the PDF plugin but this is not the standard behaviour. Also, there is no guarantee that a PDF plugin has been installed on all client computers.

You could create a [auto-print pdf](http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=157&t=Create_an_Auto_Print_PDF) where the document is set to invoke its print command when it is opened in a PDF viewer application. This would work even if the document is saved and then opened outside the browser.